# Game over for [multiplayer]

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we burninate [multiplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)? It has over 1000 questions and sounds like a very meta tag.

Comment: I'm not sure about the questions tagged also [tag:android] but the ones tagged [tag:unity3d] could be legit.

Comment: @rene still seems meta even in unity that could to x-y questions.

Comment: @rene what kind of question do you see being OT for the unity3d ones?

Comment: Meh.  I can see the tag passing points 3 and 4 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).  I'm fine with keeping the tag.  Probably couldn't hurt to go through it and clean it up though.

Comment: @NathanOliver i see it as it really can't stand on its own in our community.

Comment: Tags don't need to stand on their own, they can be supported by other tags.